# How to get number of subscriber and views count for youtube channel using v3 api in php?

Tags: youtube

I have worked on a client project to get number of views and subscriber count for a given channel id.Can anyone provide me the documentation or code sample in php?

Answer (score 0):

I was stuck here too a couple of days ago. Probably too late but may help others.
You can get the entire data by sending a GET request to this API:

```
https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/channels?part=statistics&id=<channelid>&key=<ga-key>
```

Make sure you have access to google API and have enabled Youtube API in your development console.